# Como fazer o PHPMailer e o envio dos valores a um banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Estou tentando enviar os dados do formulário para um e-mail usando o PHPMailer (isso já está funcionando) e aproveitar para incluir esses dados em uma tabela de banco de dados MySQL.

Não funcionou, imagino que o erro esteja no código.

```
<?php
// Adiciona o arquivo class.phpmailer.php - você deve especificar corretamente o caminho da pasta com o este arquivo.
require_once("phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// DEFINIÇÃO DOS DADOS DE AUTENTICAÇÃO - Você deve auterar conforme o seu domínio!
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.xxx.com.br"; // Seu endereço de host SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Define que será utilizada a autenticação -  Mantenha o valor "true"
$mail->Port = 587; // Porta de comunicação SMTP - Mantenha o valor "587"
$mail->SMTPSecure = false; // Define se é utilizado SSL/TLS - Mantenha o valor "false"
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // Define se, por padrão, será utilizado TLS - Mantenha o valor "false"
$mail->Username = 'cursos@xxx.com.br'; // Conta de email existente e ativa em seu domínio
$mail->Password = 'juliana2017'; // Senha da sua conta de email

// DADOS DO REMETENTE
$mail->Sender = "cursos@xxx.com.br"; // Conta de email existente e ativa em seu domínio
$mail->From = "cursos@xxx.com.br"; // Sua conta de email que será remetente da mensagem
$mail->FromName = "Form do site"; // Nome da conta de email

// DADOS DO DESTINATÁRIO
$mail->AddAddress('xxx@gmail.com', 'Bruno'); // Define qual conta de email receberá a mensagem
//$mail->AddAddress('recebe2@dominio.com.br'); // Define qual conta de email receberá a mensagem
//$mail->AddCC('copia@dominio.net'); // Define qual conta de email receberá uma cópia
//$mail->AddBCC('copiaoculta@dominio.info'); // Define qual conta de email receberá uma cópia oculta

// Definição de HTML/codificação
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// DEFINIÇÃO DA MENSAGEM
$mail->Subject  = "Formulário de Contato"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Atendimento:</strong> ".$_POST['atendimento']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Curso:</strong>        ".$_POST['curso']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Nome:</strong>             ".$_POST['nome']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Certificado:</strong>  ".$_POST['certificado']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>CPF:</strong>          ".$_POST['cpf']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>E-mail: </strong>      ".$_POST['email']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Celular:</strong>      ".$_POST['celular']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Outro telefone:</strong>" .$_POST['telefone']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Rua:</strong>          ".$_POST['rua']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Número:</strong>       ".$_POST['numero']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Complemento:</strong>  ".$_POST['complemento']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Bairro:</strong>       ".$_POST['bairro']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Cidade:</strong>       ".$_POST['cidade']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Estado:</strong>       ".$_POST['uf']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>CEP:</strong>          ".$_POST['cep']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Como nos conheceu?:</strong> ".$_POST['facebook'].", ".$_POST['instagram'].", ".$_POST['google'].", ".$_POST['outrasformas'].", ".$_POST['indicacao']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= " <strong>Termo:</strong> ".$_POST['termo']."<br>"; // Texto da mensagem
$mail->Body .= "
<BR><BR>
<strong>DADOS PARA O CONTRATO</strong>
<BR><BR>
".$_POST['nome'].", portadora do CPF: ".$_POST['cpf'].", reside no endereço; ".$_POST['rua'].", Nº: ".$_POST['numero'].", ".$_POST['complemento'].", ".$_POST['bairro'].", ".$_POST['cidade'].", ".$_POST['uf'].", CEP: ".$_POST['cep']."";


// ENVIO DO EMAIL
$enviado = $mail->Send();
// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();

// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado do envio (sucesso/erro)
if ($enviado) {
  echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
  echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
  echo "<b>Detalhes do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

////////////// INSERT TO MYSQL ////////

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$rua = $_POST['rua'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$complemento = $_POST['complemento'];
$bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
$cidade =  $_POST['cidade'];
$uf = $_POST['uf'];
$cep = $_POST['cep'];
$strcon = mysqli_connect('mysql.xxx.com.br','xxx','juliana2017','xxx') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome, cpf, email, celular, telefone, rua, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, uf, cep)VALUES ($nome, $cpf, $email',$celular, $telefone, $rua,$numero, $complemento, $bairro,$cidade, $uf, $cep)";
mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
mysqli_close($strcon);
echo "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!";
```

Comment: os values devem estar todos entre aspas simples  .....VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf', '$email', '$celular', '$telefone',' $rua', '$numero', '$complemento', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$uf', '$cep')";

Answer (score 1):

os values devem estar todos entre aspas simples

```
  .....VALUES ('$nome', '$cpf', '$email', '$celular', '$telefone','$rua', '$numero', '$complemento', '$bairro', '$cidade', '$uf', '$cep')";
```